# 3C273 jet mass estimate

Tags: quasars, resource-request, astronomical-jet, estimate, synchrotron-radiation

In this picture of 3C273, we can see a jet—estimated to be around 200,000 light-years long—being emitted.

[image]

I'm trying to find an estimate for the mass of the jet. It's a stream of electrons, accelerated through synchrotron radiation (see [here](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Courvoisier/Cour6.html)). There seems to be lots of information on its spectroscopic properties and the mass of the quasar (886 million solar masses), but I can't find an estimate for the mass of the jet itself. Does anyone know of a source I could look at to give me some idea?

Comment: Have you looked here: [https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0605530](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0605530)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger Warning:  Major hacking going on here.
[edited from 1 ly to 1000 ly diameter]
Scaling from the image, I'll approximate the jet diameter as 1000 ly . So there's a volume of roughly 2e4*1e6 * pi/4 cubic ly.   For absolutely no good reason, I'll propose an electron ejection density of 1E6 per cubic km -- at least those are round numbers and easily scalable if anyone can find references to actual calculations/measurements --, so using 1 cubic ly = 8.468e+38 cubic km, I get 1.33e+56 electrons in the jet.